# How to pass arguments to parent from a child component down at 2 levels

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and encountered a scenario where i have a two level child structure from parent. At the level 2, there is dynamic list of child components and each child has an associated checkbox. So how do i pass some data (like assume fruit name and id) to the parent on onChange event on this child.

Comment: If you can use some code sample to illustrate the problem more precisely, that would be helpful to find the answer.

Comment: You can always pass a function from the parent to the children at level 2 ( via children at level 1 ) that sets local state in the parent on change and use the updated state to perform your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my action class where i have defined the functions and
 what actions are to be taken in case required function is called

```
 import Dispatcher from "./Dispatcher.jsx";
export function createTodo(text)
{

Dispatcher.dispatch(
{

type: "CREATE_TODO",
text

}
);


}
```

Here is my store component which is recieving the action from by dispatcher

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'events';
import React from 'react';
import Dispatcher from "./Dispatcher.jsx";
class TodoStore extends EventEmitter
{
constructor()
{
super();
this.todos=[



        ]
            }

            createNewTodo(text)
            {

                const id=Date.now();
                this.todos.push({
                    id,
                    text,
                    company:"Ibm"
                });
                this.emit("change");

            }

            getAll()
            {
            return this.todos;
            }

            handleActions(action)
            {
                console.log("todostore receied an action",action);
                switch(action.type)
                {
                case "CREATE_TODO":
{

                    this.createNewTodo(action.text);
                }


                }



            }


}
```

Here is the Featured class which calls the function createTodo(text) in todoActions component.

Then action will be fired in todoActions class and dispatcher will dispatch that action and on event change in store component event emitter emits the change event and this event gets caught in Featured Component and hence required argument is passed to this class.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router";
import {Button, IconButton} from 'react-toolbox/lib/button';
import Input from 'react-toolbox/lib/input';
import Todo from "./Todo.jsx";
import TodoStore from "./Store.jsx";
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import * as todoActions from "./todoActions.jsx";





class Featured extends React.Component {
    constructor()
    {

        super();

        this.state=
        {
        todos:TodoStore.getAll()


        }

    }
    componentDidMount()
    {


    alert("after")
    }
    componentWillMount()
    {
        alert("before")


        TodoStore.on("change",()=>{
            this.setState({
                todos:TodoStore.getAll()
            });
        });
    }
    createTodo()
    {

        todoActions.createTodo(Date.now());

    }
    reloadTodo()
    {

        todoActions.reloadTodo();

    }
   render() {



      return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
      <div>






      <h1>Featured</h1>
      <Button label='Create' accent onClick={this.createTodo.bind(this)}/>

      <table>
       <tbody>{this.state.todos.map((todo, i) => <Todo key={i} todos= {todo} />)}</tbody>
     </table>
      </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
      );
   }
}


export default Featured;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is you transport the callback as a props down the components.

Like in parent component, create your handler:

```
//keep descriptive name so you can remember later on 
handleChangeInChild2(event) {
    console.log("name:", event.target.name, ", val=", event.target.value)
    //do your stuff
}

render() {
    //sending the handler function to first child as a callback
    return <Child1 handler={this.handleChangeInChild2.bind(this)}/>
}
```

In Child1's render, pick from props and send to child2 as is

```
render() {
    return <Child2 handler={this.props.handler}/>
}
```

In final child2's render you can now install the handler on the INPUT

```
render() {
    return <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.props.handler}/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function as a props from parent to child that can change the state of the parent (assuming that the data is stored in the parent's state, then you can pass a function that contains `setState`)

Here's some example:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      data: {}
    };
    this._transferData = this._transferData.bind(this); // Don't forget to bind the function to the component
  }

  _transferData(value, checked) {
    /*
      This is the function that accept values and
      pass it to the state
     */
    let data = {...this.state.data};
    data[value] = checked;
    this.setState({
      data: data
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child1 onChange={this._transferData} />
      {/* The parent passes _transferData as a props for Child1 */}
    )
  }
}

class Child1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Child2 onChange={this.props.onChange} />
      {/* Child2 passes the passed function from Parent as a props (again) for Child2 */}
    )
  }
}

class Child2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      checked: false
    };
    this._handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this); // Don't forget to bind the function to the component
  }

  _handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      checked: event.target.checked
    });
    /*
      Then Child2 uses the function to update the Parent's state
     */
    this.props.onChange(event.target.value, event.target.checked);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="fruit"
          value="Apple"
          checked={this.state.checked}
          onChange={this._handleChange}
        /> I have an apple
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```